# Implementing a module system with Android in-app purchases

Tags: android, sqlite, in-app-purchase

I have a question regarding in-app purchases in Android. But first off, a little bit of information about what I am trying to do...

My app has a collection of "modules" that are arranged in a SQLite database arranged like this. These modules are differentiated simply by a column that designates what module that particular entry belongs to. What I want to do, is create an in-app purchase system where the user can download additional "modules" of content.

What is the best way to arrange and handle this data? Is it a good idea to keep the database setup and somehow implement a system where the in-app purchase adds to the database? Is it possible to keep track of this in the case that the user deletes the app or app data? I want to make this system as dynamic as possible, so that the user is not shown a message saying there is additional content available if they have already purchased and installed it.

The development on my app has not begun yet, so any other arrangement of data can easily be explored. For reference purposes, each "module" will have about 50-60 entries, and the plan is to have anywhere between 5-20 "modules" so there will be a good chunk of data.

Sorry for the plethora of questions all at once. If you need any screenshots to get a better idea of the data, or if I didn't do a good enough job in explaining what I am trying to do, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

For me it sounds like you need user accounts serverside. There you keep track of the necessary things about the user, like what he/she has bought, etc. In other words, the database is in a remote place, not in the app, so you can delete and reinstall as you wish and the data is still available.

In order to identify the users, this will help: http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Is it also possible to keep track of the user's purchases through their account they are using for the market? For example, when you buy an Android phone, and if you don't have a Gmail account, the OS let's you create one to sync and use Google Play. Perhaps it is possible to differentiate who purchased what with a quick check to a server with that account? I want to avoid implementing a login system just set, as from my experience it does put off a user quite a bit from the get go.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment...ran out of space...So what about the data itself? Let's say I figure out a way to check what data the user is supposed to have. Then, should it all be stored in a local database (makes the app usable offline) and should the data be added to the database with the purchase? I guess my question is, what form does the purchase take? Is it simply a SQLite additional table? And how to make the application recognize any new tables put in without having to give the app an update itself? Thanks!

Comment: You are right with the first comment, I searched and found this: http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify.html it will probably be useful.

Comment: I don't understand fully the questions in the second comment. Just think about which data makes sense to be stored locally and which remotely. Main differences, locally you can access offline, remote not. Locally the access is faster. Locally will be removed / not available if the user removes the app, or reset the device, or use another device, remotely you control if and when the data is deleted.

Comment: Databases are just a way to persist data, the exact form of it depends of what exactly you need. It can be only an additional column in an existing table, or a new table... depends what exactly you want to track. How to know if there's new data, well, you don't have to update the app, of course, you just need to query the database (whereever it is). You could just need to save in a database the ids of the bought modules, and show notification of new content available only when the id of the content is not in the database... etc.